# RewriteRule for sub domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So I am trying to set up a subdomain on my home server called "maps"

i want

*.TLD.com and www.TLD.com to be handled as normal

but maps.TLD.com

to actually point to a local server (MapServer on same box) on a different port (lets say 8080 for arguments sake, ive not installed it yet)

really struggling, everything i tried either pushed everything to this port, OR breaks the httpd.conf

Comment: You want `http://maps.TLD.com/` to `"...actually point to a local server..."`. Give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it
what was needed was

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost>
    ServerName www.TLD.com
    ServerAlias TLD.com

    DocumentRoot C:/public_html
    <Directory>
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost>
    ServerName maps.TLD.com 

    DocumentRoot C:/maps
    <Directory>
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```